# Is there a common way to render out pdf files in a human-readable format on the command-line and keep the general layout?

Tags: bash, command-line, pdf, postscript

I'm imagining something deeper than *pdftotext* (part of [poppler-utils](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armel/poppler-utils)), because what I was imaging would be possible, would be to retain most of the layout on a virtual page, e.g. pipe this through a pager like *most*, and then possibly even get symbol-based replacements of simple graphics and such.

A chain of commands that you commonly use, or a script, would be really interesting to see.

I've added the word "common" to the question, to avoid asking a question that requires too much opinion, which is against the Stack Exchange ethos.

A big priority here would be if the solution was totally portable, like for example to use even in single-user mode on a Mac, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`pdftotext` does have a `-layout` option:

```
   -layout
          Maintain  (as  best  as  possible) the original physical
          layout of the text.  The default is to  ´undo'  physical
          layout  (columns, hyphenation, etc.) and output the text
          in reading order.
```

It doesn't do graphics though.